# Teaching a Pre-Calculus Course using Basic Mathematics by Serge Lang

Tags: textbooks, precalculus

I am considering using Basic Mathematics by Serge Lang as the primary text for my High School Pre-Calculus course. My students have all spent a year working through the first six books of Euclid and have passed Algebra II. Is there anyone who has used this book in a class? What recommendations would you have based on your experience?

Comment: Without commenting on the specific book, I'll say that I used one of his books in graduate school and it was pretty much the worst thing that ever happened to me; it literally set back my career, possibly permanently. In private discussion with a colleague of Lang's, I was told "Oh yes, we all knew he wrote terrible books..."

Comment: It sounds like you are at a very unusual school. It may be hard for others to give you advice without knowing more about your situation.

Comment: I'm not looking for particular advice, rather for the experience of others who have used this particular textbook.

Comment: My guess is that very few teachers have used it as a text. You know your students, you know yourself, and (hopefully) you know the text. Are they a good fit for each other?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: It may be good to collect a list, perhaps on MathOverflow, of "Books that could set back your career". I'm sure such a question would be sunk as "too opinion based", so I haven't asked it. I imagine it would be a service to be warned, though.

Comment: Well, I start teaching the course tomorrow. I'll let you know.

Comment: So far, so good. The students are having a bit of trouble making their way through the proofs, but there have been a few moments of "Wow, I see how it works!" which make it worthwhile.

Comment: How is your course so far? I am also considering using the same book for my Pre-Calculus course. I am already using Lang's book for my calculus course so using his pre-calculus textbook seems to be a natural choice.